# Problem with natbibapa and \shortcite

Tags: citing, natbib, apacite

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{c,
  author  = "Anne Author and Bert Buthor and Carla Cuthor",
  title   = "Final Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 3009,
  volume  = 9,
  number  = 10,
  pages   = "11--12",
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\begin{document}
\citet{c} says something.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

In my thesis I need to cite the name and year of authors, so I use natbib.
But for more than two authors, I wish that only first name is displayed followed by et.al.
However since I use natbib, \shortcite cannot be used.
Are there any other ways to overcome this problem?

Comment: `apacite` implements the citation and bibliography style prescribed by the (now outdated) 6th edition of the APA publication manual. One rule in 6th-edition APA style is that citations with three to five (? I think, I can never remember the exact cut-off numbers) are cited in full the first time and as first author + "et al." in subsequent citations. This is what you get here as well.If you don't want this behaviour APA and `apacite` is probably not for you. In that case a simple `natbib` format may come closer to what you'd like to see. ...

Comment: You could replace `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` with `\usepackage{natbib}` and `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` with `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}`.

Comment: My school requires 6th-edition APA style but with using et al for more than two authors. I think what I will do is only cite the years and manually type the authors name. @moewe

Comment: Ugh! Why does every school need to add their own rules to already complex styles such as APA?

Comment: The statement "I need to cite the name and year of authors, so I use [the natbibapa option]" contains a *non sequitur*. You can easily create authoryear-style citation callouts *without* specifying the `natbibapa` option. Just use `\citeA` instead of `\citet` and `\cite` instead of `\citep`. See section 4.1, "The 'classic' apacite commands", for more information. With this setup, using `\shortciteA` and `\shortcite` to generate citation call-outs with truncated author lists is no problem at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement,

> I need to cite the name and year of authors, so I use [the natbibapa option]

contains a *non sequitur*: One can easily create authoryear-style citation callouts *without* specifying the `natbibapa` option. Just use `\citeA` instead of `\citet` and `\cite` instead of `\citep`. See section 4.1, "The 'classic' apacite commands", of the user guide of the `apacite` package for more information.

With this setup, using `\shortciteA` and `\shortcite` to generate text-style and parenthetic-style citation call-outs with truncated author lists is no problem at all.

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@article{c,
  author  = "Anne Author and Bert Buthor and Carla Cuthor",
  title   = "Final Thoughts",
  journal = "Circularity Today",
  year    = 3009,
  volume  = 9,
  number  = 10,
  pages   = "11--12",
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{apacite}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}

\begin{document}
\shortciteA{c} says something.
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If one never wants the first citation to give the full name I think it is a good idea to try and get `\cite` and friends to behave like `\shortcite` and friends from the start. `\let\citeA\shortciteA` etc. etc. could help there (since `apacite` has no option to turn off that behaviour.)

Answer (score 2):

It is a feature of APA style (6th edition, is which `apacite` implements) that lists of three to five authors are given in full on the first citation and only as first author + "et al." in subsequent citations.

For one-off occurrences `apacite` defines commands to override that such as `\shortcite`.

---

If you are using `apacite` with the `natbibapa` you are telling `apacite` to hand some control over the citation commands over to `natbib`, that means that some of the specialist citation commands `apacite` usually defines are not available any more. One of these is `\shortcite`.

The [`apacite` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/contrib/apacite/apacite.pdf) says (§4.2 *Using `natbib` for citations*, p. 15)

> The full author list is obtained by adding a star after the command, for example, `\citet*{key}`.
>   There is no separate command for the short author list, but it can be obtained with the construction `\shortcites{key}\citet{key}`.

So one option would be to say

```
\shortcites{c}\citet{c}
```

the first time you cite `c`. Subsequent citations will be abbreviated to first author + "et al." anyway. But of course that is extremely tedious, error-prone and overall doesn't feel right.

But the section from the `apacite` manual that we quoted above contains more information

> With the `natbibapa` option, `apacite` loads `natbib` with the options `longnamesfirst`
>   and `sort`.

So with `natbibapa` we get the long author list on first cite thanks to the option `longnamesfirst`. If we can turn off that option, we're back in business.

Unfortunately, `natbib` offers no interface to turn off this option. Once `natbib` is loaded with `longnamesfirst` there is no option to turn it back off. So we have to resort to internal commands. The option sets an internal boolean called `NAT@longnames` to true, so we set it to false.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
\makeatletter
\NAT@longnamesfalse
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{c,
  author  = {Anne Author and Bert Buthor and Carla Cuthor},
  title   = {Final Thoughts},
  journal = {Circularity Today},
  year    = 3009,
  volume  = 9,
  number  = 10,
  pages   = {11--12},
}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{document}
\citet{c} says something.

\citet{c} says something.

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: Author et al. (3009) says something.//Author et al. (3009) says something.]

---

If you are looking for the answer to the same problem but without the option `natbibapa` (i.e. with `apaciteclassic`), the simplest answer I could find was to say

```
\let\cite\shortcite
\let\citeA\shortciteA
\let\citeNP\shortciteNP
\let\citeauthor\shortciteauthor
\let\citeauthorNP\shortciteauthorNP

\let\maskcite\maskshortcite
\let\maskciteA\maskshortciteA
\let\maskciteNP\maskshortciteNP
\let\maskciteauthor\maskshortciteauthor
\let\maskciteauthorNP\maskshortciteauthorNP
```